Nginx 405 Not allowed when redirecting from a third party website
So i have an angular project that goes to a payment page url of a third party website. And after the payment is complete it redirects the user to the angular project page. But during redirection I am getting Nginx 405 not allowed error. If i reenter the url and press enter it doesn't show the 405 error anymore and the page loads perfectly.
I am using nginx as my server in digital ocean droplet. This is the etc/nginx/sites-available/default file content.
server {

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name shahir.com; # managed by Certbot


        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
         listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
         ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/shahir.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/shahir.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
         include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
        ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 ;
        server_name _;
        rewrite ^ https://$host$request_uri permanent;
}


besides rewrite i have also tried return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
but it didn't work either.
Also I have checked the error.log file
[crit] 1178958#1178958: *176 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 212.102.40.218, server: 0.0.0.0:443

I don't know if it's because of the ssl or wrong nginx configuration i am getting this issue. Solutions or tips regarding this will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
